# Why doesn't rsDebug work?

Tags: android, renderscript

I've inserted an [rsDebug](http://developer.android.com/reference/renderscript/rs__debug_8rsh.html) method in the [Android RenderScript](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/package-summary.html) sample "Fountain", but I'm getting no messages out of logcat.

Here's a code snippet to demonstrate what I've tried:

```
int root() {
    float dt = min(rsGetDt(), 0.1f);
    rsDebug("dt", dt);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been working with the renderscript example CarouselView example from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip&can=2&q=) and here is what I did to get rsDebug to work:

1. Added debuggable="true" to the application tag in the manifest file:

   ```
   <application android:debuggable="true">
   ```
2. Added

   ```
   \#include "rs_debug.rsh"
   ```

to the carousel.rs renderscript file.

Comment: I can't get it to work either, even with samples that run perfectly. I tried explicitly with `<application android:debuggable="true">` even though it complains about that being a bad practice since it automatically does it now. `#include "rs_debug.rsh"` with no slash, right? I get a compile error with the slash (hey, I have tried everything at this point).

Answer (score 1):

Besides the answer of Dave i want add following hint:

Messages in renderscript are outputted in the "Verbose"-level.
So it may be easy to ignore them because you are in the wrong level.

So in Android Studio you can change the logcat-output here:

[image]

Comment: They should be available in "Debug" as well actually.